# Transforming a 2D point using a 2D transformation matrix

Tags: matrices, geometry

I am manually supporting two-dimensional matrices, similiar to what is explained in [air.Matrix](https://airsdk.dev/reference/actionscript/3.0/flash/geom/Matrix.html).

What I do not understand is how transforming a 2D point into another 2D point using a 2D matrix works, given that it consists of 4 coordinates. Which ones to pick, or should I combine them all, and in which way? Right now I am implementing a `deltaTransformPoint()` function, which is given a point in the pretransform coordinate space, not taking $(t_x, t_y)$ into consideration, according to air.Matrix from AIR SDK.

[image: Properties (1)]

Where $(t_x, t_y)$ are translation coordinates. $(a, d)$ are the $(x, y)$ coordinates used when scaling or rotating an image, while $(b, c)$ are the $(y, x)$ coordinates used when rotating or skewing an image.

Am I supposed to do something like $((a, d) + (b, c)) \times p$, where $p$ is the point to be transformed?